# Does every frame contain the same number of time-like and space-like vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

For a pseudo-Riemannian manifold M of signature $(p,q)$, would it be valid to say that every frame (ordered basis) $e\in LM$ contains $p$ time-like vectors and $q$ space-like vectors?

If this does not hold, is this true for the weaker case of a Lorenzian manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the usual Minkowski metric with $\eta = \text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. Then $(1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,1,1)$ is an ordered basis with 1 time-like vector, 1 null vector, and 2 space-like vectors.

Comment: Okay could we make the statement that there are at most $p$ time-like vectors and at most $q$ space-like vectors?

Comment: You always get the same number for *orthonormal* frames (this is called Sylvester's Law of Inertia). For arbitrary frames you have no control.

Comment: @CamWhite If by “frame” you mean *any* basis, then no. A basis can consist entirely of time-like vectors, for example. However, if a frame is an *orthogonal* basis then your initial claim holds.